# Geometry node which allow me to skip every odd frame in the object animation

Tags: geometry-nodes, alembic

I need help to build a node tree which would allow me to skip every odd frame in the object's animation. Basically, I need a tool that behaves just like a stepped modifier but in geometry nodes.

##### Reason

My object can be either an alembic or a sequence obj which means it doesn't have keyframes to which I could apply a stepped modifier.
I also need the object to be the only one that skips frames whilst the rest of the scene runs at 24 fps, so I can't use 12 fps globally.

##### OBJ Sequence test

I found this node tree on the web that converts the obj sequence to animation. Unfortunately I am only able to slow down the animation meaning that, although one position takes 2 frames, the overall animation is twice as long. I need one position to hold for two frames, but the animation to still have the same length, meaning it sort of throws away every other frame.

[image: node tree screenshot]

##### ALEMBIC test

I have no idea what a node tree for alembic would look like, :-) but we managed to make the tool I need in Cinema 4D using Xpresso, I believe it can be done in blender as well.

I would be grateful for any advice :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can replace your Divide with a Snap (still a Math node so just use the dropdown), setting Increment to 2.

Comment: Wow, that was quick thanks a lot, this works. Any idea how to solve it for the alembic? Do you know what the node tree should look like?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Alembic.

Comment: Nevermind thank you for advice :-)